# When $f(0) = 0,$ is it always true that $G(0) = 0,$ where $G$ is the antiderivative of $f$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, graphing-functions

I have a hunch that it is, but it would be nice if somebody could confirm / disprove it for me.

Thank you.

**Edit**
Is it when the constant of integration is equal to zero?

Comment: Antiderivatives of $f$ are a family, each differs by a constant.

Comment: Furthermore, this would not work with $\sin$ and $\cos$

Comment: @peterwhy Ah, of course.

Comment: $f(x) = \sin x, x \in [0, 1]$, $G(x) = - \cos x, x \in [0, 1]$. $f(0) = 0$ but $G(0) = -1$.

Comment: @peterwhy Apart from trigonometric identities, and assuming that the antiderivative of $f$ that we are working with has a constant equal to zero, are there any more examples?

Comment: Another example: Take $f(x)=e^x-e^{-x}$. Its antiderivative is $e^x+e^{-x}+C$.

Comment: I believe $f(x) = \ln(x+e) - 1$ works as well, @ColdNumber your + should be a - ?

Comment: @ColdNumber $f(0)$ is not equal to zero.

Comment: @Krijn yes, thanks! fixed it.

Comment: @Taylor The problem is that for a function, which part is "the function" and which part is "the constant" is not always clear. Picking a totally unrelated example:
$$\begin{align*}
u(x) &= -2\sin2x\\
-\int 2\sin2x\ dx &=\cos 2x + C_1
\end{align*}$$
But I can also do
$$\begin{align*}
-\int 2\sin2x\ dx &= -\int 4\sin x \cos x \ dx\\
&= -\int 4\sin x \ d(\sin x)\\
&= -2\sin^2 x + C_2
\end{align*}$$
Now, tell me, what is "the antiderivative" that has "the constant" zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Take $f(x) = xe^{-x^2}$.
Clearly, $f(0) = 0$.

The integral function of $f(x)$ is:

$$G(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}  te^{-t^2} dt 
= \left.-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t^2}\right|_{t=-\infty}^{t=x} = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}$$

In this case, $G(0) = -\frac{1}{2} \neq 0.$

Comment: @Taylor, you are welcome, man :D

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not true in general. Let $F(x)$ be a anti-derivative of $f(x)$ then $$\int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = F(x) + k$$ now, even if $F(0) = 0$ there's still the $+ k$ constant to contend with.

An example would be $f(x) = x\exp x$ then we have $$F(x) = \int x\exp x \, \mathrm{d}x = e^x (x-1) + k$$ Now, even if $k = 0$, then $F(0) = -1$ whilst $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, another counterexample is given by $f(x)=e^x-e^{-x}$, whose antiderivative is $F(x)=e^x+e^{-x}+C$.

Note that $f(0)=e^0-e^0=0$, and $F(0)=e^0+e^0+C$, so $F(0)=0\iff C=-2$.

Variations of the coefficients of the exponentials or the exponents would force you to choose a different value for $C$:

- $f(x)=2e^x-e^{-x}$, with antiderivative $F(x)=2e^x+e^{-x}+C$. Then $F(0)=0 \iff C=-3$
- $f(x)=e^{2x}-e^{-x}$, with antiderivative $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}+e^{-x}+C$. Then $F(0)=0 \iff C=-\frac 32$.

---

However, your statement holds for polynomial functions:

Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots a_nx^n$.

Since we want $f(0)=0$, the constant term $a_0=0$, so $f(x)=a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n$.

The antiderivative of $f(x)$ is $F(x)=\frac{a_1}{2}x^2+\frac{a_2}{3}x^3+\cdots+ \frac{a_n}{n+1}x^n+C$, so requiring that $C=0$ does ensure that $F(0)=0$.

Answer (score -2):

No. The simplest example I can think of?
$$f(x) = x$$
Then $G(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} + C$, which is not guaranteed to be always $0$.

Comment: I down voted your answer because I wanted to know if it is true for the case $G(0)$, which, in your example, does indeed yield zero.

Comment: You asked is it true that $G(0) = 0$ when $f(0) = 0$. This is different from assuming $G(0) = 0$.